# How to install psycopg2 using pip in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I seem to be having an issue. I need to install db_utils using pip install db_utils in python, but to do that, I need to first pip install psycopg2 (not the binary). I get certain errors that I can't seem to desifer. I use a mac and get the following messages:

**1. pip install psycopg2:**

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Users/shaansaharan/uraEnv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-install-0rx6_2cr/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-install-0rx6_2cr/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-56e88jv6
             cwd: /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-install-0rx6_2cr/psycopg2/
        Complete output (23 lines):
        running egg_info
        creating /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-56e88jv6/psycopg2.egg-info
        writing /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-56e88jv6/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-56e88jv6/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-56e88jv6/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
        writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-56e88jv6/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        
        Error: pg_config executable not found.
        
        pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
        containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
        option:
        
            python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
        
        or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
        
        If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
        'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
        
        For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
        <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**2. pip install db_utils**

```
Collecting db_utils
  Using cached db_utils-0.4.6-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting mysql-connector-python>=8.0.15
  Using cached mysql_connector_python-8.0.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (319 kB)
Collecting awscli>=1.16.32
  Downloading awscli-1.19.67-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.6 MB 20.4 MB/s 
Collecting jinja2>=2.10.1
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 125 kB 567 kB/s 
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.4
  Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42 kB 1.0 MB/s 
Collecting psycopg2>=2.8.2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/shaansaharan/uraEnv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-install-mp88whx9/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-install-mp88whx9/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u8n74xr7
         cwd: /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-install-mp88whx9/psycopg2/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u8n74xr7/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u8n74xr7/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u8n74xr7/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u8n74xr7/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/sz/qgv_1m8x3jv7vgympqys_mph0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-u8n74xr7/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

    enter code here
```

thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

for my case I had similar error and had to follow the instruction when running the command

```
brew link openssl
```

I hope this was helpful

Comment: I get the following when I try that:

Comment: try to install homebrew (it is a very well know package manager here is the link: https://brew.sh)

Answer (score 0):

you can install binary of it:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```